# Laravel Custom Rule Validation with Array of Form Fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to access attribute values in the custom validation rule I created.

**HTML**

```
Designation Dropdown
<select name="resource[{?}][designation]>
<option value=1>First Value</option>
<option value=2>Second Value</option>
</select>

Allocation Dropdown
<select name="resource[{?}][allocation]>
<option value=1>First Value</option>
<option value=2>Second Value</option>
</select>
```

**Controller Code**

```
'resource.*.allocation' => ['required',new ResourceQuotation()],
'resource.*.designation' => 'required',
```

**Laravel Custom Rule - ResourceQuotation**

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{

$designation = request()->input("resource.*.designation"); <!--//I am confused here, how to access the designation array value since we might have multiple.!->

$allocations = ResourcePrice::select('allocation','fixed_allocation')->where('id',$designation)->first();

 if($allocations->fixed_allocation=1){
    $this->message = "Maximum allocation allowed is 10%";
    return false;
 }

 else{
   return true;
 }

}

public function message()
{
 return $this->message;
}
```

First I thought to use a loop but how to display individual message errors? I found this tutorial but they are using it for a single value comparison, not with different field attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `passes()` method in the ResourceQuotation rule.

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $designationArray = request()->input("resource");

    foreach ($designationArray as $index => $designationData) {
        $designation = $designationData['designation'];

        $allocations = ResourcePrice::select('allocation','fixed_allocation')->where('id', $designation)->first();

        if ($allocations->fixed_allocation == 1) {
            $this->message = "Maximum allocation allowed is 10% for index $index";
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: we need to adjust $this->message to array as well? Its giving same error on 2 fields if i select multiple designation which meets the condition